# Gmail notifications aren't working as expected

Tags: notifications, gmail, sync

Gmail notification doesn't work correctly for me. I think it happened after the latest Gmail application upgrade.

I tried to clear Gmail data and cache, but to no avail.

- I get new email notification after I mark read email as unread. It didn't used to happen before.
- I have new email notification so I access inbox from android and the notification disappears. Then I get new email notification after I delete the new email from pc.

Any suggestion how to make the notification work the way I want/expect?

<sup>I have HTC Desire running cyanogenmod 7.1 with Gmail v2.3.5.2</sup>

Comment: try clearing the data for the gmail app - Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications - Gmail App

Comment: I tried to clear data & cache before posting my question. It didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting which inboxes are being synced? (Inbox vs Priority Inbox, etc)

Comment: @earthmeLon: yes but it didn't help. On the other hand, why it should help? It's not relevant to this issue.

Comment: @Radek It solved a similar issue for me.  I apologize it did not resolve your issue.

Comment: Worth trying :-)

Comment: Did you ever solved this issue?

Comment: No :-( I didn't.

Comment: Are you marking the mail as unread on your phone or on another device? I don't get any notification on the device that I use to mark the mail as unread, but I've always got the new mail notification on other devices. Definitely had that ever since I've had both a phone and tablet, which is over a year now.

Comment: Hm, I am on Android 4.0.3 and it looks that it works ok.